# How to create this simple model with arrow and text on the top?

Tags: math-mode, graphics, math-operators

How to create this simple model with arrow and text on the top ? Regards
[image: How to create this simple model with arrow and text on the top ? Regards]

Comment: Have a look in the LaTex-manual regarding the picture-environment, and also the documentation of the pict2e-package, http://ctan.mirrorcatalogs.com/macros/latex/contrib/pict2e/pict2e.pdf. You will find lot of tips there.

Comment: May be this answer can also help you: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/99501/1952

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without a package and simple LaTeX commands:

```
\documentclass{article}
\unitlength=1cm
\newcommand\test[2]{%
\begin{picture}(3,2)
  \put(0,0){\line(1,0){3}}     \put(0,2){\line(1,0){3}}
  \put(1.5,0){\vector(1,2){1}} \put(1.5,0){\vector(-1,2){1}}
  \put(0.45,2.1){#1}\put(2.35,2.1){#2}
\end{picture}}

\begin{document}
\test{G}{A}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Typically, we don't answer 'draw this for me' or similar questions, but I'm feeling nice.

You can use the TikZ package like so:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{>=stealth}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (-0.5,0) -- (2.5,0) (-0.5,-2) -- (2.5,-2) ;
  \draw [->] (0,0) node [anchor=south] {\(A\)} -- (1,-2) ;
  \draw [->] (1,-2) -- (2,0) node [anchor=south] {\(G_1\)} ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```